# Why does the notion of Paragraph Vector make sense?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

In paragraph vector modeling, they refer paragraph as a memory information, together with context words to predict the target word. I can't see why a paragraph will be useful information to predict the target word.
Should the paragraph include the target word?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqwFo.png)

Can anyone give me examples of how to do it? What's D here? Is the paragraph ID also a one hot paragraph vector?

For example , I have  paragraph A, B, C and word a,b,c,d,e,f,g.
Paragraph B is the sequence of abcdefg.
The document is A+B +C
If I want to train this document and I want to predict word d.
What's the input paragraph here?
I know the word input should be hot word vector of a,b,c,e,f,g,if the window size is 7.

Answer (score 1):

The image you posted is from paper Distributed Representations of Sentences and Documents by Quoc Le and Tomas Mikolov. You can find detailed explanation of paragraph vectors in section 2.2.

When training word embeddings we usually take vectors of words from the neighborhood of certain word. When using paragraph embedding you can think about it as adding one more word for each training sample we process. It is like more global word that is in a way describing the whole paragraph, not just the few words that were selected as context.

The representation of paragraphs is the same as representation of words. You are encoding which paragraph you want to use with one-hot vector and the paragraph embedding itself is being trained while the corpus is processed. During training you can again think about it as some hidden word inserted to every context of given paragraph.

When calculating the values in the hidden layer you can use addition or concetating. The paper I mentioned is using a concetating so the resulting vector is one half paragraph vector and one half vector calculated from word embeddings.

Comment: Does the paragraph include the word that we want to predict ?

Comment: The paragraph vector in this paper does not take into account what words are really in it. You just take n-th paragraph, assign it a random vector and then train this vector. So in you case you would have 3 paragraph vectors A, B and C and for every N-gram sample in your training you would use that paragraph vector, which the N-gram originated from.